# How can we detect when user closes browser?

Tags: angular

I mean, I want to track when a user leaves the app, closing browser or tabs.

Components and Directives has a lifecycle hook called ngOnDestroy, which is called when the component is destroyed, but it can't catch when the user leaves the app

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnDestroy() {
      alert(`I'm leaving the app!`);
  }

}
```

If the user closes the browser, the alert is not executed.

Answer (score 82):

You can listen to the `unload` or `beforeunload` events like this:

```ts
export class AppComponent {
  @HostListener('window:unload', [ '$event' ])
  unloadHandler(event) {
    // ...
  }

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', [ '$event' ])
  beforeUnloadHandler(event) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

See also

- [Detect browser or tab closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event

Use IDE breakpoints to verify triggers.

Comment: it is possible to get only tab/browser close.

Comment: AFAIK there is only `unload` and `beforeunload`. There might be some tricks or hacks to get some more information, but I have no knowledge about.

Comment: If you find any resource inform me. Thanks for quick response. :)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The above method is not working for me...i put an alert, but it is not triggering..angular version 2.4.10

Comment: The alert will never be showed.. since the dialog will be gone by that time. Put a breakpoint on the developer tools so you can see it being trigged.

Comment: This event is also triggered on refreshing the page not only on closing tab.

Comment: If anyone is using `alert` just to verify then it won't work. Use only Visual Studio Code for debugging even develop tools breakpoint won't work.

Answer (score 1):

`visibilitychange` event is an alternative

```
export class AppComponent {
   
  @HostListener('document:visibilitychange', ['$event']) 
  visibilityChange($event: Event) {
    
    if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
      console.log("document.visibilityState === 'hidden'")
    }
  }
}
```

[MDN usage notes for visibilityState say (May 31, 2022)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event#usage_notes)
:

> This event fires with a `visibilityState` of `hidden` when a user
> navigates to a new page, switches tabs, closes the tab, minimizes or
> closes the browser, or, on mobile, switches from the browser to a
> different app.

For Safari `beforeunload` event is also recommended at [Chrome Developers Blog: Page Lifecycle API by Philip Walton (May 27, 2020 )](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/page-lifecycle-api/):

> Safari does not reliably fire the `pagehide` or `visibilitychange`
> events when closing a tab (webkit bugs: 151610 and 151234), so in
> Safari you may need to also listen to the `beforeunload` event in
> order to detect a change to the hidden state. But since the
> `beforeunload` event can be canceled, you need to wait until after the
> event has finished propagating to know if the state has changed to
> hidden.