# Angular 2 - Does ngOnDestroy get called on refresh or just when navigate away from component?

Tags: angular

I am trying to figure out if ngOnDestroy in Angular 2 gets ran on a refresh or just when someone navigates away from the page?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

On refresh or when you navigate away from the current page (except for routing), then `ngOnDestroy` won't be called. The application will just be destroyed by the browser.

Only when Angular2 removes the component from the DOM because you move away or you call `destroy()` on a dynamically created component, then `ngOnDestroy()` is called.

You can listen to `beforeunload` and `unload` yourself if you need some action to happen before the application is destroyed by the browser.

See also

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload
- [How can we detect when user closes browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642589/how-can-we-detect-when-user-closes-browser/37642657#37642657) (Angular)

Comment: Does component gets destroyed when the browser is closed?

Comment: @Ritesh no, only when Angular itself destroy it and it won't have time anymore when the browser is closed. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642589/how-can-we-detect-when-user-closes-browser/37642657#37642657

Comment: Yes, I did verify this behavior. Thanks.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer What do you mean by 'because you move away'? How does it differ from 'navigate away from the current page'.

Comment: The difference is whether the Angular router shows a different content on the same page or a different page is loaded. In the later case there is nothing Angular can do because the browser just kills it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer how to identify if it is same page or different page loaded?

Comment: @srikanth_k sorry, but I don't understand your question. A different page is a different application. What do you want to identify from where?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer,I navigated to some /xyz path which loads a component with ngOnDestroy. When I am manually changing browser url to root path ('/'), ngOnDestroy is not getting called.

Answer (score -3):

You can do one thing and it works like a charm.
Create a test guard and apply on your component.

Create a service with a BehavioralSubject. and whenever go to your component the guard will check and in the guard initialize your subject, as and when it gets initialized it will check if it is getting subscribed somewhere. In your component in the ngOnInit subscribe to this subject and from there call the destroy method.

Comment: Could you please provide an example? I don't think this answer is very helpful without it.