# A post request in Angular 4 doesn't work using @HostListener

Tags: angular, browser

Host listener doesn't work. 
The function which triggers the request is being called but, the post-operation does not invoked. 
Can anyone help with this?

app.component.ts

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
onWindowClose($event) {
    console.log('market unlocked');
    this.unlockAlias();
    return true;
}

constructor(private router: Router, private service: Adal5Service, private http : Http) {
    this.service.init(config);
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.service.handleWindowCallback();
    this.isAuthenticated = this.service.userInfo.authenticated;
}

unlockAlias() {
     const apiEndPoint = environment.baseUrl + environment.unLockAlais;
    const body = '{"uid": "' + this.service.userInfo.username + '" }';
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    this.http
        .post(apiEndPoint,
        body, options)
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log("unlocked");
        }, error => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
        });
}}
```

Comment: Have you tried `.toPromise()` instead of `subscribe`?

Comment: Instead of using the HostListener on the window:beforeunload event, why not put the function call on ngOnDestroy() ?

Comment: @Roysh yes .toPromise() also dosen't work

Comment: @rrd https://stackoverflow.com/a/40468409/4808975

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after i altered the unlockAlias() to return the http result , which is an Observable and subscribed it on ('window:beforeunload') event.

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
onWindowClose($event) {
    this.unlockAlias().subscribe();

 unlockAlias() {
    const apiEndPoint = environment.baseUrl + environment.unLockAlais;
    const body = '{"uid": "' + this.service.userInfo.username + '" }';
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(apiEndPoint, body, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to `POST` asynchronously in the `beforeunload`, as the function will terminate and the user will navigate away from the page before your subscription resolves.

You could make a `synchronous` (blocking) call yourself, but `Angular` does not support that (because it's a bad idea), so you would have to do it the old fashioned way.