# Angular how to call any service while closing window/tab

Tags: angular, rest, routes

how to call any service while closing window/tab I have tried the beforunload
and canDeactive When I close the browser service get hitting in chrome debugger but not reaching the actual service any hacks there pls help

Comment: Hi Deepak, you need to give more detail about what you are trying to achieve. I suggest that you put together the code you have using www.stackblitz.com happy to look at this if you create one.

You might also might find something looking at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999842/angular-2-execute-code-when-closing-window which yours seems to be a duplicate of..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I able to make it work with the unloadNotification event its work in IE Also. should useful for anyone..

```
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  unloadNotification($event: any) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify($event) + '#event')
    if (!this.canDeactivate()) {
       this.cancelTransaction();
        $event.returnValue = "Are you sure you want close?)";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can call any service by closing a page.You need to call service in hooks lifecycle **ngOnDestroy()** method.

```
ngOnDestroy(){
   //call your service here.
}
```

Reference:-

https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy

Comment: This will not work because ‘onDestroy’ is only fired when the component is removed from the DOM, not when the tab is closed.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40468409/6288171

Comment: Then give him to a solution Mr.nclax.

Comment: I did in a comment on his question already