# when to unsubscribe from SSE Event Source event in angular (close/refresh case)

Tags: angular, server-sent-events, eventsource

I am using some EventSource in a service in my APP.

I would like to close all the connection when the browser is closed/refreshed.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129319/how-can-i-handle-browser-tab-close-event-in-angular-only-close-not-refresh) post

Right now, this is what I added to my service.

```
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  onBrowserClose() {
    this.clearAll();
  }

  clearAll() {
    if (this.eventSource) {
      this.eventSource.close();
    }
    this.callbacks = new Map<string, (e: any) => void>();
  }
```

is there a better solution ?

Answer (score 3):

you can use [**`ngOnDestroy()`**](https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy) for unsubscribing events

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  if (this.eventSource) {
    this.eventSource.close();
  }
  this.callbacks = new Map<string, (e: any) => void>();
}
```

> I would like to close all the connection when the browser is closed/refreshed.

```
this angular life cycle method will be called when component is going to destroy
```

Comment: this supposedly doesn't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468267/angular-2-does-ngondestroy-get-called-on-refresh-or-just-when-navigate-away-fr since the component is not destroyed in angular workflow when you close the browser or refresh the page