# How To Check Browser close Condition for Angular 4 Application?

Tags: angular, laravel, typescript

I am building an Angular Application which has Login & Logout Functionality. On click of logout the user status is updated in the Database using Laravel API, but I need to handle the browser close condition, If user closes the browser, then I need to update status in the Database, but i dont know how to call Laravel API on browser close. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are events you can listen to and act accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642589/how-can-we-detect-when-user-closes-browser

Comment: Are you talking about Laravel events or Angular events ?, because Angular events not called when browser close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this solution

add `window:beforeunload` event

```
import { Component , HostListener } from '@angular/core';
export class AppComponent {
    @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
    doSomething($event) {
        /// code
    }
    constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: Hi, is it enough if I put this in app.component.ts? Or do I have to put this method in every component?

Comment: Hi @Dseaster , You can use in `app.component.ts`

Answer (score 0):

Add `ngOnDestory` life cycle hook in your `AppComponent` (your root component).

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestory {
...
    ngOnDestory() {
        // API Call
    }
...
}
```

According to Angular.io documentation, `ngOnDestory` is lifecycle hook that is called when a directive, pipe or service is destroyed.

Comment: Is this ngOnDestory() hook will call on browser close?. Because as per my knowledge these Life cycle hooks are used only when we are in application.

Comment: I tried you solution but didn't worked in my case :(

Comment: did you tried `onbeforeunload` ? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ev_onbeforeunload