# Save data before leaving page or changing parameter in Angular component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

given following paths:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ListComponent },
  { path: 'items/:id', component: ItemOutletComponent,
    children:[
      { path: '', component: Section1Component },
      { path: 'page2', component: Section2Component, },
    ]
  }];
```

how to ensure that a custom method called `applyChanges()` on `Section1Component`, resp `Section2Component` each time:

1. user navigates away from the page
2. the `:id` url parameter changes
3. as a bonus question, also when user closes the browser?

I currently load resource model in `ItemOutletComponent`, I create FormGroup on each section component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
     section1: new FormGroup({
       prop1: new FormControl(),
       prop2: new FormControl()
  });
  this.formGroup.pathValue(this.model);
}

applyChanges() {
  Object.assign(this.model, this.formGroup.value);
}
```

All I need is to ensure that formGroup changes are applied back to model at appropriate time. There is no Save button on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use navigation events to detect that user is about to navigate to different location (or not) and do required actions

https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events

Bonus answer:
You will have to use native JS events like `windiw:unload` and `window:beforeunload`

[How can we detect when user closes browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642589/how-can-we-detect-when-user-closes-browser/37642657)

But in it will not work in some cases (eg. killing browser), but that is totally browser dependent