# Leave site alert when closing browser using angular Shows Error Blocking Alert on beforeunload and unload

Tags: angular

How to achieve Leave site alert using Angular when user try to close the browser

I tried using Hostlistener beforeunload and unload.

I paused by debugger i checked. It showing the below error the

1) Blocking Alert After beforeunload
  2) Blocking Alert After unload

Comment: @HostListener('window:onbeforeunload ', ['$event'])
    beforeunloadHandler(event) {
        alert('fffff')
    }

Comment: So with using Hostlistener, you didn't succeed?

Comment: What does the first note say in the documentation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we detect when user closes browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642589/how-can-we-detect-when-user-closes-browser)

Comment: @arjun when developer tool is open its working . when its closed it not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use unload and beforeunload events to when you want to deal with this kind of issues.Below is the code will help you to get solution.

```
export class AppComponent {
  @HostListener('window:unload', [ '$event' ])
  unloadHandler(event) {
    //If you want to do something when page gets reloaded or on leaving page
  }

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', [ '$event' ])
  beforeUnloadHander(event) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I hope you will get your solution.

Comment: thank you for your answer .but its not working with by code

Comment: i checked in debugger. it showing Blocked alert  during beforeunload.
homes:1 Blocked alert  during unload.

Comment: code working fine but alert is blocking . thats why

Comment: You can use `return false;` instead of alert.For this I have also edited my code. @Angulardoubt

Comment: When developer tool is opened its working fine . when it's close its not working

Comment: You can go mentioned link [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phh712).I have written code in stackblitz. You can check it.

Comment: I think this is browser specific issue.Can you please try in Firefox.I have just tested it.It works fine in Firefox.@Angulardoubt