# How to clear local storage after close the browser?

Tags: angular, local-storage

How to clear local storage after close the browser? Using google, i found only this:

```
@HostListener("window:onbeforeunload",["$event"])
clearLocalStorage(event){
    localStorage.clear();
}
```

But it cleans local storage after updating the page, but I don’t need it. I also know that can use `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage`, but this is not suitable, since I do need to save the session not only in one browser tab. How else can I clear the local storage if I close the browser?

ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const potentialToken = localStorage.getItem('auth-token')
    if (potentialToken !== null) {
      this.auth.setToken(potentialToken)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you can handle only your website tab event.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible.

Comment: @AJT_82 Got it(((

Comment: Maybe this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642589/how-can-we-detect-when-user-closes-browser/37642657

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    window.onunload = function () {
            window.localStorage.isMySessionActive = "false";
    }
    return undefined;
};

window.onload = function () {
            window.localStorage.isMySessionActive = "true";
};
```

Comment: Wow, if `getItem` and `clear` are set instead of `isMySessionActive`, this will work)